# setup.py sdist flattings package file structure, removes intermediate folders

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py, pypi

File structure:

```
.
|-- rdir
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- core
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- rdir_core.py
|   |   |-- rdir_node.py
|   |-- generateHTML
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- rdir.py
|-- setup.py
```

Setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
  name="rdir",
  version="0.40",
  description="....",
  author="lhfcws",
  author_email="lhfcws@gmail.com",
  url="...",
  license="MIT",
  packages=["rdir"],
  scripts=["rdir/rdir.py"],
  install_requires=['colorama', 'pyquery'],
  )
```

Commands:

```
sudo python setup.py install         #local install
sudo python setup.py sdist upload    #pypi upload
```

Try `from rdir import rdir` in other path like home directory, only meets with:

```
ImportError: No module named core.rdir_core
```

Of course it works well if I import rdir in the project directory.
And I looked into `site-packages/rdir.egg-info/`, I found that all the .py files were moved into a flat structure:

```
EGG-INFO
├── PKG-INFO
├── SOURCES.txt
├── dependency_links.txt
├── not-zip-safe
├── requires.txt
├── scripts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── generate_page.py
│   ├── rdir.py
│   ├── rdir_core.py
│   └── rdir_node.py
└── top_level.txt
```

I also tried if I just `import rdir_core` in rdir.py, it compiles correctly. So I guessed there's sth wrong with my setup.py, and I read some demos, some setup.py of famous python projects on github and some official manuals. I changed my setup.py according to those reference, but all failed. I have no idea so I have to ask for help.

Is it something wrong with my setup.py? Or is there anything I've missed?

Or please show me a good example of a setup.py of multi file structure projects. Thank you!

BTW, if these above cannot offer you enough information, please look at [rdir on Github](https://github.com/Lhfcws/rdir)

Comment: First I suggest never ever do `sudo python setup.py` as you potentially destroy your system-wide Python installation. Please use virtualenv instead https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#virtual-environments

Comment: Can you post your full `setup.py` also?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Thank you for ur reply. Actually I do the install to test my setup.py, not to really use this package by python install. And basically ignoring import and author information, that's my entire setup.py now.

Comment: It cannot be your full `setup.py` there is no single import statement in the code you shared, it should fail with an error.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Yeah, I've ignoring it while posting the code to make it clear. I see what you mean and I've added it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's the problem of the `packages` keyword in your `setup.py`. You should list sub packages as well as the top level package.

```
packages=['rdir', 'rdir.core', 'rdir.generateHTML'],
```

Or, using `find_packages`, which you already imported

```
packages=find_packages(),
```

I didn't try the sdist stuff, maybe it's just collecting all py files as scripts.

P.S. You can use `python setup.py build` to test the result folder structure.

Comment: I tried your method with find_packages() and still it will generate a directory called `scripts-2.7` containing all the py files in flat structure. However, in the lib directory it remains the correct structure.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Ray, I've solved by myself.

It is the problem of `scripts` in the `setup.py`.

The project was a flat structure, so it works well before 0.30. However in my computer, the scripts options will install the `script` to `/usr/local/bin` and generate a flat structure in EGG.

If I dont remove the old scripts in `/usr/local/bin`, python interpreter will check those scripts under `/usr/local/bin` first and cause error.

So the solution is:

1. remove `scripts` in `setup.py`
2. set `packages=find_package()`
3. sudo rm /usr/local/bin/rdir*

Thanks to you all.